# SYSPRO Integration

Tags: xml, integration

When I call a Business Object in SYSPRO I get this error:

```
ERROR in Call ERP Service: ERROR: 15 ""Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s"" in SYSPRO_BusinessObjectCall
```

This is specifically for the SORTCL Business Object. Have any of you guys worked with this Business Object and can assist me please?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but that's a .NET error that is thrown when you try to .ToString() a null. My guess is you're invoking SYSPRO via E.NET WCF Service and have not provided a required parameter correctly.